# How to compile less in webpack?

Tags: webpack, less

I want to compile all **.less** files from a folder in order to load them via **link** tag when I run **npm start**. No css files are generated. When I run **npm start** my project starts without, no message with **.less** keyword. I walked through webpack tutorials and can't setup less compiler environment.

**package.json**

```
{
 "name": "webpack-demo",
 "description": "",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
   "watch": "webpack --watch",
   "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js",
   "server": "node server.js",
   "webpack": "webpack"
 },
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "devDependencies": {
   "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
   "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
   "express": "^4.16.3",
   "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
   "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
   "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
   "less": "^3.0.1",
   "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
   "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
   "webpack": "^4.6.0",
   "webpack-cli": "^2.0.15",
   "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.1.2",
   "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3",
   "webpack-merge": "^4.1.2"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "angular": "^1.6.10"
 }
```

}

**webpack.dev.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
  module: {
       rules: [{
         test: /\.less$/,
         use: [{
           loader: 'style-loader' // creates style nodes from JS strings
         }, {
           loader: 'css-loader' // translates CSS into CommonJS
         }, {
           loader: 'less-loader' // compiles Less to CSS
         }]
}]
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you importing the less files somewhere? Rules just tell webpack what to do with imports of less files. It won't look for them on its own.

Comment: @lukas-reineke yes, I forgot to load the files from entry point, thanks !!